# UPDATE значения

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста есть две таблицы message_group и messages структура messages такова

INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `group_hash`, `from_id`, `message`, `date_ms`, `time_ms`, `is_read`) VALUES
(1, 28874, 5, 'привет', '2014-01-11', '00:10:01', 0),
Как сделать UPDATE сообщения на 1.Типа прочел пользователь.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `group_hash` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `date_ms` date NOT NULL,
      `time_ms` time NOT NULL,
      `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_group` (
  `user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: так какова же структура?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_hash` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_ms` date NOT NULL,
  `time_ms` time NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_group` (
  `user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Answer (score 1):

ну если я правильно понял `is_read` - это поле отвечающее за прочтенность.
Тогда запрос такой

```
UPDATE `messages` SET `is_read`=1
WHERE id={id}
```

где id-номер сообщения

Comment: Так работает проверял, а как сделать, вот юзер с ид 1 написал юзеру с ид2, вот что бы только мог юзер с ид2 как заходить в сообщения делалось упдейт на ис_реад, просто я вот например пишу, и я сам же его делаю упдейт

Comment: ну когда user2 открывает ссылку на открытие сообщения - тогда и вставляете запрос на.

Другой вопрос - я не вижу у вас привязки в таблицах: кто написал сообщение и для кого оно, и все это привязка к id сообщению